# how to change theme of magento e commerce?

Tags: php, magento, configuration, themes, e-commerce

how to change theme of magento e commerce ??

Answer (score 12):

Go to admin >> system >> design >> and Add custom magento theme >> here you will see the theme which you have created in folder structure, just select and save the theme and then just delete or refresh the cache and refresh your web page, that's all.

Comment: After much messing about in the config->design tab. This fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: how can i change theme for single website?

Answer (score 7):

It looks a little fiddly, but I think this is the relevant section of the user guide:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes#head-how-to-assign-a-theme

> Navigate to the Magento admin panel (ie.www.mydomain.com/admin), then the Design configuration tab (System -> Configuration -> Design tab).
>
> - In order to manage your store design in the website-level, select the name of your website from the dropdown, then apply the following steps.
> - In order to manage the design from the store view-level, select the name of your store view from the dropdown, then apply the following steps.
>
> Step 1
>   From the Design tab, in Current package name, enter the name of the interface in which your new theme resides. Magento will automatically load the interface called ‘default’ if this box is left blank.
>
> Step 2
>   In Default (under Themes heading), enter the name of the new theme you’d like to load to your website/store. If you leave this box blank, Magento will automatically load only the theme called ‘default’ (Remember, no matter how you configure the design tab, Magento will automatically load the theme called ‘default’. If you assign a theme in the admin, that theme will simply load higher up in hierarchy, but will load along with the theme ‘default’. This will change in the upcoming stable release however, to give you full control over what themes are loaded into the store). Should you choose to load the theme separately depending on file type (layout, templates, skin or translation files), enter the name of the theme from which to grab the according file types.
>
> Step 3
>   When you’re done, click the button “Save config” and reload your store – Voila! You now see your new theme reflected in the frontend.

Answer (score 3):

To change theme of magento ecommerce
Go to admin -> system -> configuration select design and give your theme name.
After doing above changes delete var/cache.

Answer (score 1):

it is nothing like **Wordpress**, I can assure of that!

I bought a book, called [**Magento 1.3. Theme Design**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/book-magento-13-theme-design/) and it helped me creating a new theme, as well understanding the bits that are put together in magento.

The book explains how to install themes, images, how things work as well it passes several chapters changing the [Blank Theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/518/blank-theme) in order to be able to give the read a good approach to the Theme feature in Magento.

Go to the [**Magento chat room**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/chat) as well (WHAT? IRC? is that thing still alive??) you can find pretty good guys that can help you when you get to a wall, but don't expect that they will do everything for you.

Hope it helps.